# Is there a D plugin currently available for Xcode 4.3?

Tags: xcode, macos, ide, d

Is there a D plugin currently available for Xcode 4.3? I tried to follow the link provided on the [wiki](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?EditorSupport#IDEs), but the link (http://michelf.com/projects/d-for-xcode/) appears to be broken*. I did a search on Github and the [project in question](https://github.com/michelf/d-for-xcode) hasn't been updated since early last year (March 28, 2011).

Update:

[*] It seems it was just me, I've check again and it loads fine.

Comment: I've just downloaded ZIP files from there... Site works.

Comment: Ahh yes, it seems to be working for me again (updated the question accordingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To Xcode 4 users: D for Xcode is only partially working with Xcode 4 currently; version 3 of Xcode is fully supported.

It seems not - I'll edit this answer if full support comes back. Till then I've been using SublimeText (it only has highlighting - autocomplete or precompile checking).